# Cannot draw straight line polygon in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, digitizing, polyline-creation

I tried to draw polygon by using add polygon. It should be a straight polyline and then become a polygon but it turns to a curve line like arc (circular line) so that I couldn't draw a polygon. It's very strange. I download QGIS 3.18 and the result is the same. I don't know how to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have activated the icon `Digitize with curve` on the upper left. De-activate it:

[image]

**Edit/Update**

In QGIS 3.26, you have more options, see screenshot. If you can't find the icon, maybe the toolbar is deactivated. Go to Menu View > Toolbars > and check the box next to Advanced Digitizing Toolbar.

[image]

Comment: I de-activated the icon and it works. Thanks Babel.

Comment: Great! As a new user, please note that this site tries to avoid thank you messages. It encourages you to accept answers (hit the checkmark) that were helpful and/ or upvote them.

Comment: I have the same issue in 3.26 and cannot find the day to de-activate it. Are you able to help?

Comment: See updated answer